# Can't remove "\t" at the beginning of a string

Tags: python

I have tab occured at the beginning of a string in a list, I'm uploading. I've tried all the methods I've found to remove it, but it doesn't work

Actually you can see what I've tried in the code itself. Nothing works

```
# 2D List I got [['12/20', 'Instrument', 'Maintainance', '\tDeb', 'Pb', 'Tool', '5']]
# \tDeb - is the one with tab, I want to remove
import re
for line in list_2D:
    for piece in line:
        re.sub(r"[\n\t\s]*", ' ', piece)
        piece.replace("\t","")
        piece.replace("\\t","")
print(list_2D[0][3])
# Result -> "   Deb"
```

As a result I want to get any string with similar issue without that tab.

Comment: `piece = piece.replace('\t', '')`

Comment: Yes! That's what worked!
Thanks!
Feel stupid now...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about trailing whitespace you can use `piece.strip()` to remove all enclosing whitespace.

Alternately you can do something like `re.sub("^\s+", '', piece)`

Comment: Just tried it and still doesn't work

'import re
piece = "\tDeb"
if "\t" in piece:
    print("Working on piece:", piece)
    print('"\\t" in piece:',"\t" in piece)
    piece.replace("\\", "")
    re.sub("\t", '', piece)
    re.sub("^\s+", '', piece)
    print(piece)'

here's what I get

Working on piece:  Deb
"\t" in piece: True
 Deb

It still exists